# How can I split a numpy array into two new numpy arrays with different sizes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, google-colaboratory

I am very new to coding and I have a question about numpy arrays. So I have data stored in a numpy array `(40, 512, 752, 1)`, so 40 images of size 512 by 752 with one channnel, and i want to divide this into two arrays of `(36, 512,752,1)` and `(4,512,752,1)`. Does anyone know how I can do this or the code I can use?

Kind regards!

Comment: Do you want to do it randomly or just split?

Comment: I would like to do it randomly too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about random selection:

```
image1 = images[:36, ...]
image2 = images[36:, ...]
```

Comment: And how can you solve it when you want a random selection?